# (Strange ListView item transition when in second HubSection but not first

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

For some reason, only the first item in a `ListView` in the second `HubSection` of a `Hub` control animates on entrance, but a `ListView` in the first `HubSection` animates as expected. You can replicate it like this:

1. Open Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.
2. Create a new blank windows store app.
3. Open MainPage.xaml.
4. Set the contents to this:

   ```
   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
       <Hub Header="my app">
           <HubSection Header="section">
               <DataTemplate>
                   <ListView>
                       <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                       <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                       <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                       <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                   </ListView>
               </DataTemplate>
           </HubSection>
           <HubSection Header="section">
               <DataTemplate>
                   <ListView>
                       <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                       <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                       <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                       <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                   </ListView>
               </DataTemplate>
           </HubSection>
       </Hub>
   </Grid>
   ```
5. Run the app.

The first `ListView` animates in (slides left), but only the first item of the second `ListView` transitions in. How can I make the whole list transition in?

Here's a GIF screencast of what it looks like (I added an extra page with button on it to show the transition easily):

[image: Screencast]